# Dynamic Clock Stops Ticking

Tags: dynamic, date-and-time

I want a dynamic timer to tell me how long it has been since a file update. I have coded a simple timer for this, but an hour or two in after completing an update, the dynamic timer stops responding and just reads "0 seconds since last update".

I think the same problem happens when using the Dynamic Clock example from Mathematica:

```
Dynamic[DateString[], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

Initially, this clock works fine. But similar to my basic timer, after about an hour or two the time on the clock just stops updating. If I save the notebook running the dynamic clock code above, close the file and re-open the notebook, the clock shows the correct time and is ticking like it should.

Is there a way for the Dynamic clock to continually read the correct time without closing and re-opening the notebook file? I am currently using Mathematica 12.

Comment: Do you have to restart the notebook, as you write, or is it enough to reevaluate the cell with the `Dynamic` content in it?

Comment: Nah. Re-evaluating the cell just sets the time to the current time and does not update. I suspect that the cell continues to dynamically update the value, but that it just doesn't display the updated value in the notebook

Comment: Since this is very time consuming to try to reproduce, can you give us _very precise_ and very specific steps to reproduce? Please also include `SystemInformation["Small"]`.

Comment: The instructions should start with restarting the front end.  For example: 1. start the front end 2. open precisely one notebook 3. evaluate `Dynamic[DateString[], UpdateInterval -> 1]` 4. minimize Mathematica and do not touch it for 12 hours. Does the timer stop if you follow these precise steps?  If you have other notebooks open, if you scroll the notebook, open the help browser, or interact with Mathematica in other ways, that could interfere with the process, so do not do that.  Can you find a set of simple steps in this spirit that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try your steps before going to be tonight

Comment: Tested this and the clock is still running! I restarted my PC, closed all unnecessary startup programs, followed your above suggestions, and all is working fine. I think the problem may be being caused by a background process that monitors my PC vitals. I think this is what causes my screen to sometimes glitch (looks like a very quick refresh of desktop) and think that this visual bug may be the culprit of the clock/timer stopping.

Comment: It could be caused by some other interaction with Mathematica (in my opinion this is more likely a problem with Mathematica than interference from another program).